# Give permission to debian-transmission to write into a www-data directory

Tags: permissions, directory, transmission

I want the transmission-daemon to have permission to write to a directory called `/opt/www/` that already has the owner set to www-data(in order for the web server to serve files in it)

The transmission daemon responds with a permission denied error when I set it to my download directory. How can I give it permission to write in this directory while maintaining the www-data ownership?

Sorry if it's a bit confusing I will clarify if I was unclear.
Thanks!

Basically: `/opt/www` needs www-data to be able to be served as a webpage, but at the same time I want transmission to be able to write files to that folder. How can I do that? By default transmission runs on the user debian-transmission

Comment: You talk of two folders `/opt/www` and `/home/username/Downloads` could be more specific.

Comment: I attempted to clarify in my edit now @George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `debian-transmission` write permission on the directory using ACLs:

```
sudo setfacl -Rm u:debian-transmission:rwX /opt/www
sudo setfacl -Rdm u:debian-transmission:rwX /opt/www
```

This sets both the current permissions and default permissions (ones inherited by new files/folders).

Comment: Please what's the `X` for thought it should be `x` ?

Comment: @George from `man setfacl`: "execute only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission  for  some  user  (X)". It's a better option than simply giving execute permissions (x).

Comment: I also thought `setfacl user` only affects _files_ not _folders_ and `setfacl group` did.

Comment: @George you're thinking of setuid and setgid, which are a different concept. This is setting ACLs, and ACLs may include setuid/setgid permissions as well.