# Node modules have 755 permissions, what permissions should I set so that npm don't require sudo?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, npm

I'm using a framework which runs `npm` and `webpack` automatically, the directory `/usr/lib/node_modules` have 755 permissions which require to run `npm` through `sudo`. The framework I use doesn't allow adding `sudo` to the command.

Now I need to install npm packages in global form (e.g., `npm install webpack -g`) without using `sudo`.

What permissions will be OK for `/usr/lib/node_modules`? If I set 777 permissions will that be OK and secure?

Thank You!

Comment: Presumably related to [I made /usr/local/ world writable, is it secure?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/868854/i-made-usr-local-world-writable-is-it-secure)

Comment: Easier to use ACLs (like in my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/867337/158442, just change username and path to values suited to your case)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to alter *permission* of `npm` to be able to use it without `sudo`. TO set up `npm` to run without `sudo` follow these steps:

Option 1:

1. Get path of npm directory:

   ```
   npm config get prefix
   ```
2. If you got `/usr` **go to option 2** else change owner of npm directories to yours:

   ```
    sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
   ```

Option 2:

1. Create directory for global installations:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
2. Configure to use that directory:

   ```
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   ```
3. Open or create `~/.profile` and add this:

   ```
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. Add this also to your `~/.bashrc` file (optional) :

   ```
   export PATH=/home/username/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript:/home/username/.npm-global/lib/node_modules
   ```
5. Refresh the files:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Test by running:

   ```
   npm install -g jshint
   ```

source:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

http://www.competa.com/blog/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/

Comment: A nice detailed answer, let me try it!

Comment: That's how I use _npm_ on my system.

Comment: I'm using Zshell, so I need to add the stuff to ~/.zshrc in the step 4 ?

Comment: And do I need to change it for Zshell, or it will work as such?

Comment: sure that is right.

Comment: Add it to that shell too.

Comment: Please remember to source those files after adding.

Comment: what do you mean by "to source those files" ?

Comment: You meant keep the backup of the dot files ?

Comment: Is just to refresh the file like this `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`...

Comment: Oh. :)
I restarted the terminal and it worked.

Comment: ok same thing then cheers :).

Comment: You really should replace "if you got `/usr`" with "if you got anything that isn't under your home directory". And, since anything under your home directory is almost certainly owned by you anyway, you might as well leave option 1 out entirely, and just skip straight to option 2.

Comment: Should the path be set in both files?

Comment: Also, step 4 (modifying `.bashrc`) in your second option should be unnecessary: your `.profile` will be run automatically when you first log in, and any changes to `PATH` made in it will be inherited by subshells, so repeating the changes in `.bashrc` is redundant and will just needlessly bloat your `PATH` with duplicate entries. (You probably do want to add something like `export NODE_PATH=~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH` to `.profile`, though.)

Comment: @ilmariKaronen yes step 4 is not needed, updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: @BradyDean no it should not, updated OP to reflect that.